# Помогите пожалуйста составить SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

Привет! Прошу вашей помощи.
Есть уже select с большим количеством join и с длинным условием where.
Но так же есть еще одна незаджоиненная таблица criteria с двумя интересующими меня колонками. В одной из них criteria_group_id содержатся типы критериев - это числа от 1 до 5, а в другой appl_type_id значения этих критериев - это либо 1, либо -1. Есть в этой таблице еще колонка appl_id с уникальным идентификатором, по которому можно сделать джоин к уже написанному селекту. Т.е. у каждого appl_id в criteria_group_id есть пять значений от 1 до 5.

В итоге мне нужно добавить к селекту еще 5 колонок "критерий 1", "критерий 2" и тд. с соответствующими значениями из appl_type_id.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы вы приложили примерную схему https://erdplus.com/ используя инструмент. А дальше в принципе зная команды ON, алиасы и where проделать данную операцию.

Comment: 1. Предлагаю определиться с тем, на какой БД вы это хотите сделать: у вас в тегах и mysql и sql server  
2. Разворачивание значений строк (appl_type_id) в колонки - уже не совсем реляционный подход, но в sql server можно решить вашу задачу с применением pivot  
3. есть еще более громоздкие решения, но не вижу смысла их приводить до получения информации об используемой БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самы простой способ приджойнить таблицу 5 раз с разными алиасами для каждого типа.

```
SELECT
...
cr1.appl_type_id as cr1_value,
cr2.appl_type_id as cr2_value,
...
JOIN criteria as cr1 ON cr1.appl_id = таблица.id AND cr1.criteria_group_id = 1
JOIN criteria as cr2 ON cr2.appl_id = таблица.id AND cr2.criteria_group_id = 2
...
```

Comment: только надо учитывать, что производительность запроса будет очень низкой